# How to disable annoying autocomplete popup on Fedora Linux?

Tags: keyboard, autocomplete, laptop

I'm running Fedora Linux 37 on a laptop computer with a touch screen. Occasionally, some process or something triggers and I start seeing this really obnoxious text autocomplete prompt whenever I type anything.

[image: textbox prompt]

(The popup doesn't show up in "print-screen", so I had to take a picture using my phone)

This is a LibreOffice Writer window; I attempted to type the word "test" on my keyboard the normal way, and I see this popup. It's *everywhere*, every time I enter text in Writer, or Emacs, or the Firefox search bar. Anything that's vaguely a text field shows this popup. And as long as it's there, typing anything lags *really* badly to the point that my keyboard is almost unusable. I can't seem to figure out what triggers it, and when it starts showing up, the only way to get rid of it is to log out and back in.

Needless to say, I've never intentionally installed any software that can do this. Can anyone identify what process or operating system component is triggering this popup? What am I doing that occasionally causes it to activate? And more importantly, how can I disable or uninstall it?